# Blank row is added to my DataGridView when working with a binding list

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` that I can add test data to my data grid view but when I want to enter anything manually (through textboxes and drop down boxes), I just get a blank row added to my data grid view

This is the code I have: This is to get to the form where data is entered manually

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmAddReptile frmAddReptile = new frmAddReptile();

    frmAddReptile.ShowDialog();
    _ReptileList.Add(_Reptile);
}
```

Then, on that form I have

```
internal Reptile _Reptile;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _Reptile = new Reptile();
    _Reptile.Name = txtName.Text;
    _Reptile.Country = Convert.ToString(cbxCountry.SelectedItem);
    _Reptile.Province = Convert.ToString(cbxProvince.SelectedItem);
    _Reptile.Town = Convert.ToString(cbxTown.SelectedItem);
    _Reptile.Collector = txtCole.Text;
    _Reptile.Length = Convert.ToInt32(txtLen.Text);
    _Reptile.Coordinates =txtCo.Text;
    _Reptile.Weight = Convert.ToInt32(txtwe.Text);
    _Reptile.Date = Convert.ToString(dtpDate.Value.ToShortDateString());

    this.Close();    
}
```

Then, once the button is clicked only a black row added to my data grid view.

Ok i have now figured out if i add everything to the samewindows form it works(adds to the data grid view)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _Reptile = new Reptile();
        _Reptile.Name = txtName.Text;
        _Reptile.Country = Convert.ToString(cbxCountry.SelectedItem);
        _Reptile.Province = Convert.ToString(cbxProvince.SelectedItem);
        _Reptile.Town = Convert.ToString(cbxTown.SelectedItem);
        _Reptile.Collector = txtCole.Text;
        _Reptile.Length = Convert.ToInt32(txtLen.Text);
        _Reptile.Coordinates =txtCo.Text;
        _Reptile.Weight = Convert.ToInt32(txtwe.Text);
        _Reptile.Date = Convert.ToString(dtpDate.Value.ToShortDateString());
        _ReptileList.Add(_Reptile);

    }
```

this is what i have now but how can i make it add data form a differnt form
does it have something to do with `internal Reptile _Reptile;`?

Comment: Try setting _Reptile to be frmAddReptile._Reptile. If it doesn't work, change _Reptile to be public or a get/set property instead of internal. This should solve it, then maby someone with more knowledge of Internal will tell you what you are doing wrong.